# Measure AVG for the past N days

Tags: tableau-api

I am creating a table where yesterday data and past N data is compared. The data itself is conversion rate (conversions/clicks). I want to have a calculated field which would give me an average for the past N days.

I've got data for every day, but not sure how to handle the aggregation over days.

I tried to Create a calculated field:

```
IF [Date] >= today()-[Last N Days] and [Date] <= today()-[Last N Days] THEN ZN([Conversions]/[Clicks]) END
```

But it creates 2 rows in my table: one is empty and the other is NULL

The raw data looks like this:

```
         id   conversions      clicks    date
1        1        5              50       01.09.
2        1        12             24       02.09.
3        1        2               6       03.09. 
4        1        22             56       04.09. 
5        1        22             60       05.09.
```

So I have conversion rate calculated as the following: sum(conversions)/sum(clicks) and it works fine.

So assuming that today is 05.09. I want to see the CR for yesterday, which is 39% and for the past 5 days in this case: 33,6%.

So the output would look like this:

```
         id   CR past days CR yesterday 
1        1        33.6%              39%
```

And of course there are more IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. First you need to set a parameter to specify how large the "Last N" window is. Then you use that to determine the earliest date to be included in the "Last N" group of records to be aggregated. I generated a test for you to see how this might look on [Tableau Public](https://public.tableau.com/views/ConversionTest/Conversions?:embed=y&:display_count=yes&publish=yes).